# datatables column properties

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using DataTables table component and one of the column has very long lines of data. Currently this data basically shows by extending the column width to as much as needed to fit the data and thus adding a horizontal scrollbar.

I want to restrict column to extend like this and the text to wrap.

this is how the current code looks like

```
var dt = $(document).ready(function() {
    var dt =$('#feedback-data-table').DataTable( {
        ajax: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:7101/Oats/rest/v1/testidmap?onlyData=true&limit=999",
            dataSrc: "items"
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "Test Name", data: "TestName" },
            { title: "User Activity Info (~ separated)", data: "Useractivityinfo"}

        ]
    } );

} );
```

please advise how to achieve this. adding width:"100px" like this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use CSS rule `word-break: break-all;` for the column containing long text without any spaces to break words between any character.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       columnDefs: [
          { targets: 5, className: "word-break-all" }
       ]
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```css
.word-break-all {
   word-break:break-all;
}
```

See [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) for more information.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tj5d81fa/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the following for your CSS and see?

```css
table {
   table-layout:fixed;
}

th {
   word-rap: break-word
}
```

Comment: the data does not have any spaces in between so that is the reason the above css doesn't work